# update updated_at time without changing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any way I can touch a model causing the `updated_at` field to update to the current time without actually changing anything in the other fields?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `touch`

```
model.touch
```

or

```
model.touch(:updated_at) #or anyother timestamp attribute
```

Documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch)

Comment: I came across this question, but I am inside of an `after_touch` callback, so calling `touch` will cause recursion loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used this for a while, but now I use athis Rubocop cop: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.50.0/RuboCop/Cop/Rails/SkipsModelValidations and it will suggest not to use touch since it skips validations. Do you know of another way? Thanks.